# Use a text file for a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in my script like this

```
$acceptedID = array ('su', 'root');
```

I thought that eventually it would be hard to add more and more as this array would get really long.  So I wondered if it was possible to have an external file like this

```
su
root
asdf
etc.
```

and have it read in the script  as

```
$acceptedID = array ('su', 'root', 'asdf', 'etc.');
```

and have that keep changing as the external text file changes.  Is there any way to do this?  Also after the array is there, it has to run and if statement to see if it is in an array.

```
if (in_array($id, $acceptedID))
        return 'YES';
    else
        return 'NO';
```

Comment: are these 4 files in 1 folder, or 4 lines in 1 file ?

Comment: `$acceptedID = file('myList.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady 4 lines in 1 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just keep your array in an external file and include it where you want it:

**//commands.php**

```
// This file just contains a return statement which returns the the array
// with the commands

return array(

    'su',
    'root',
    'other',

);
```

**//yourscript.php**

```
// You can include your array anywhere you want
$validIds = include('commands.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

file — Reads entire file into an array

Answer (score 0):

Use this way, [`file`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) does it:

```
$acceptedID = file("myList.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Comment: I get this `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in script.php on line 5` when trying to run the if statement